# Node js watch file and get appended text

Tags: node.js

I have a file that get updated every minute, two lines of text are added every minute, i want to watch that file for changes and get the last line. This is the type of text that are added:

```
#SKJDIFH:3054456456,
name33.amd
```

When this text has been added i want to get last line meaning `name33.amd`.

Comment: And how does this relate to Node?

Comment: @MattMorgan because it's a `Node` app